# 404 error on all pages after changing directory

Tags: php

I changed the folder location of my site from www.example.com to www.example.com/users/ now but now all the links show 404 error when clicked on.

my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

application folder htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteBase /users/`

Answer (score 0):

the RewriteBase should be /users/

RewriteRule ./users/index.php